# Sri Rudram and other mantras in Pada Patha

Tags: shiva, vedic-chanting

Namaskar! Is there some place in which I can find audio files of the Sri rudram and other mantras in Pada Patha (Sometimes called Moola patha)?

Here is the Ganapati Prarthana in many different Pathas but would like to have some more audios, particularly Pada Patha.

https://youtu.be/2SJtvpCIRWo

regards!